# Waiting for window load event to register service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I stumbled upon this snippet in [Google Workbox documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started):

```
<script>
// Check that service workers are registered
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  // Use the window load event to keep the page load performant
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');
  });
}
</script>
```

How exactly page load becomes less performant without window `load` event handler?

Wouldn't it be generally preferable for service worker to hook up as early as possible, since one of main uses for it in PWA is caching?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Service workers load in the background off the main thread but they still consume computer resources and, if pre-caching, network resources. If the current rendering page takes 500KB to render and and you want to pre-cache the page to fully work offline, the service worker will also have to download that 500KB. This competes with the current page being rendered so it's advised to delay registering a service worker until after the current page is ready for the user.

You can read more about registering service workers on [web fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/registration#a_users_first_visit).

Comment: Thanks, Google's own explanation on user's first visit you've linked makes sense in the context. Consider adding the quote to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that blocking with load event listener.

you need to load all resources anyway and the service worker stores them afterwards in the browser.

next time the user visits the application, the service worker is already there. Ready to deliver resources from the browser's cache.

the service worker is not running with the main thread.

Comment: Please, clarify what you mean. *It's not that blocking with load event listener.* - why should it be blocking? As you already mentioned, SW runs in another thread. *you need to load all resources anyway and the service worker stores them afterwards in the browser* - but if SW doesn't start until the page is loaded, it won't store them after 1st visit, only after 2nd visit.

Comment: the installation part, of course, is happening in main thread. On SW activation, the service worker starts itself to cache all required assets. And on the 2nd visit they can get served from browser (offline). But it also can depend on how you store files to cache: with a fetch event listener they will be stored once fetched, which could be that it will happen on the 2nd visit...

Answer (score 0):

Please see, service worker is not just some JS files being downloaded as part of your web app. Its also a [browser implementation as an API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API). SW JS code in your web app will talk to the SW implementation of your browser to cache the files that's loaded before/after the SW JS file is loaded. Sequencing or timing of which file loads in what order is not important when it comes to SW's ability to cache.

That's the reason, browsers without SW support will not cache even if your web app is PWA compatible.